# ngmodel and ngform not working at all in angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this question was asked before , but all the solutions were about just importing `FormsModule` & `ReactiveFormsModule` from `@angular/forms` , but actually i have done this and added them to the imports , but nothing from `ngForm` or `ngModel` work as expected. The errors shown to me are:

```
" error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' " &
" There is no directive with 'exportAs' set to 'ngForm' "
```

I have tried to change the `Angular` version to an earlier version but the same issue still happens

Here are my imports

```
import { AddProductComponent } from './Features/products/add-product/add-product.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {FormsModule , ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './Features/products/product.component';
import { ProductListingComponent } from './Features/products/product-listing/product-listing.component';
import { ProductItemComponent } from './Features/products/product-item/product-item.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ProductListingComponent,
    ProductItemComponent,
    BtnComponent,
  ...........etc
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
............ etc .
```

and here is the Code of the HTML the produces errors

```
<form #myform="ngForm" class="add-product" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
```

it shows an error " There is no directive with 'exportAs' set to 'ngForm' "

and also this code ( note that product is an object initialized in my component )

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="product.Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="">
 </div>
```

this shows an error " error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' "

if i removed these ( ngForm and ngModule ) from code , the whole code works perfectly fine ...so what can i do

Comment: How did you binded your ngModel ? Can you provide some code

Comment: are you import it (in the `imports array`) in the module which your component is declared?

Comment: my imports are in the main module ( app.module.ts)

Comment: I am trying to make two way binding between a text box in my component and an object that i am creating using this syntax [(ngModel)] = "object.name" , but it is raising an error always ... also when i am trying to make this syntax in the form #myform = "ngForm" to get the whole form object i got an error also !!!

Answer (score 0):

At last I managed to solve the problem by stopping the server and run the command :

```
npm update
```

then after that restarting the server again the issue was fixed .

Answer (score -1):

Import FormsModule in AppModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ]
```

Comment: I did that actually but the problem still exists

Comment: an other thing restart ur angular dev server some time it solve problems as well

Comment: Please create a minimal example on stackblatz https://stackblitz.com/
and share here 

some times while creating example u find out what was wrong

Comment: please show them in ur question so other could see it as well

Comment: imports seems alright did u restart ur dev server ?

Comment: Thanks i have edited my post so that all people can see the code

Comment: Yes i restarted the server several times actually , i have been stuck in this for 3 hours with no solution

Comment: Please create a minimal example on stackblatz stackblitz.com and share in ur question